# Need to only fire EventTrigger one time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have an ItemsControl in which I'm animating newly added items with the following code:

**EDIT**, I have added more code as requested.

```
<ItemsControl Name="taskBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ItemEnterAnimation" AutoReverse="False">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)" From="-30" To="0">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded" >
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ItemEnterAnimation}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Grid Name="container">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that there are certain things that can cause the underlying `ObservableCollection` (`TaskList` in the sample) to send a `CollectionChanged(Reset)` event, which causes all of the elements to reload. As a result, the enter animation will get called for every single item *again*.

Is there a way to only perform this animation one time when the item is first loaded?

Comment: would it be possible to have a boolean flag that gets set to false when "certain things happen"?  Then you can use flag to be the trigger for the storyboard event.

Comment: How would I make the trigger conditional? that is, in the XAML, how would i say "After FrameworkElement.Loaded, only begin the storyboard if condition = false"

Comment: I was thinking you'd do it the other way.  The "certain things happen" events would set the flag to false.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The storyboard event is happening when the item is added in to the `ItemsControl`, that can't change, and I don't wish to manually fire the storyboard from the view model because that breaks MVVM

Comment: have a look at triggering your event w/ a data trigger rather than an event.  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Comment: Can you add your complete XAML code?

Comment: That would be impractical, the datatemplate is quite massive and doesn't provide any value. The only additional details that matter is that we're talking about a `ItemsControl` that has `ItemSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` that can fire a collection reset event, and when that happens we don't want to fire the loaded animation again on the items.

Comment: Also not sure why this was voted to close as off-topic, I've clearly identified a behavior of the framework, provided code, and am wondering how to circumvent it.